# Unsupported operand types in file.php on line 266

Tags: php, php-5.6

When I run my website, I see this error:

```
Unsupported operand types in file.php on line 266
```

Line 266 `file.php` is as the following:

```
$template_hook += $SetTemplates;
```

PHP version is 5.6.

Comment: Are you doing increment or appending?

Comment: This is for Increment if both field are Integer: $template_hook += $SetTemplates;   If you want to added string then use $template_hook .= $SetTemplates;

Comment: @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA I'm not a PHP developer. The website used to work with no issue, but recently I'm seeing this error. Also file has not changed

Comment: and which type are `$template_hook` and `$SetTemplates`?  First try to know them with `gettype()` function

Comment: @masterguru `<?php require('./file.php'); gettype($template_hook);` Is that right? I see blank page when I run in web browser?

Comment: @Saeed: No, in order to debug it better I suggest you to add this line: `echo "var template_hook=".gettype($template_hook);echo "var SetTemplates=".gettype($SetTemplates);die();` just before the line 266 inside `file.php`.  In this way you could check if both vars have the same type and are able to use the increment operant.  If not then you have to investigate further which one is damaged in previous sets of that vars.  Once fixed you sohuld remove/comment that new line in order to try again full code.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Unsupported operand types" appears if the operation with the variable types is not possible. Example:

```
$template_hook = 1;
$SetTemplates = array(1,2,3);

$template_hook += $SetTemplates;
//Fatal error</b>:  Unsupported operand types in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>5
```

The variables for the operator += do not necessarily have to be of the type integer. This is also allowed in PHP:

```
$template_hook = array(7,8,9,10);
$SetTemplates = array(1,2,3);

$template_hook += $SetTemplates;
```

As already written in the comments, the only thing that helps here is to check the type of the variable.